# WinError 10054 when adding favicon.ico to base.html django selenium StaticLiveServerTestCase

Tags: django, selenium

I am following a tutorial online and I have been able to track down exactly where this error occurs on my machine. I am on windows 8.1 SP1, and I am using the selenium StaticLiveServerTestCase(I know its slow, but its used in the tutorial)

But if I have

```
 <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{% static 'favicon.ico' %}" 
 type="image/x-icon">
```

and then run

```
python manage.py test
```

I will get a Winerror 10054: an existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. **If I remove that link tag the selenium test runs with zero problems**

Seems like a relatively benign problem as

```
python manage.py runserver
```

runs with no issues and shows the icon, but I would still like to clear it up down the road.

here is my test code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.contrib.staticfiles.testing import StaticLiveServerTestCase
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

class HomeNewVisitorTest(StaticLiveServerTestCase):

def setUp(self):
    self.browser = webdriver.Firefox()
    self.browser.implicitly_wait(3)

def tearDown(self):
        self.browser.quit()

def get_full_url(self, namespace):
    return self.live_server_url + reverse(namespace)

def test_home_title(self):
    self.browser.get(self.get_full_url("home"))   
    self.assertIn("TaskBuster", self.browser.title)

def test_h1_css(self):
    self.browser.get(self.get_full_url("home"))
    h1 = self.browser.find_element_by_tag_name("h1")
    self.assertEqual(h1.value_of_css_property("color"),
                        "rgba(200, 50, 255, 1)")              
def test_home_files(self):
    self.browser.get(self.live_server_url + "/robots.txt")
    self.assertNotIn("Not Found", self.browser.title)
    self.browser.get(self.live_server_url + "/humans.txt")
    self.assertNotIn("Not Found", self.browser.title)
```

and for reference here specific part of the tutorial I am refering to

```
http://www.marinamele.com/taskbuster-django-tutorial/template-inheritance-website-files-and-testing-with-coverage#favicon
```

**edit: I have tried the following fix but it did not work 
https://github.com/django/django/pull/1806

** added complete traceback 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0a5J.jpg

Comment: Could you post the complete error traceback? Thanks.

Comment: added complete traceback